# How to place buttons on the bottom corner of a page and have it be responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on this website as a side project. I have been trying to make this page responsive (this is my first responsive web page). So far I figured out everything except the social media buttons. I would like to place them on the bottom right corner of the page and have it be responsive however every time I do this when I resize the window they move start to move up. I have included my HTML and CSS. Thank you for all of your help.

I have tried using flexbox, bootstrap, and grid and cant get any of them to work, I am also a bit confused about which kind of CSS to use.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
       <title>Giphy Search</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"integrity="sha384ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2Zw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

       <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
       <div id="fb-root"></div>
       <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous"
        src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v4.0"> 
       </script>

       <div id="imgLogoDiv">
          <img id="imgLogo" src="/img/logo.png" alt="unable to load image">
       </div>

       <div id="divTxtField">
          <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for a gif!">
       </div>

       <div id="bs-divSearchButton">
          <button id="bs-Button" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Search</button>
       </div>
       <br>

       <div id="GifDisplay">
          <img id="gif">
       </div>

       <div id="socialMediaBottons"> 
           <div id="twitterButton">
               <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large"
        data-text="Search for a Gif!" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
               <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
           </div>

           <div id="fbButton">
              <div class="fb-share-button" data- 
  href="https://www.facebook.com/GIPHY/" data-layout="button" data-size="large"><a target="_blank"
          href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse"
          class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a></div>
             </div>  
          </div>

         <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
      </body>

     </html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url(img/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#imgLogoDiv {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: auto;
    /*height: auto
    Not sure if I should keep this since it seems to have to effect.*/
}

#imgLogoDiv #imgLogo {
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
}

#divTxtField {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

#divTxtField #search {
    border-radius: 25px;
}

#divTxtField #search:hover {
    cursor: auto;
}

#bs-divSearchButton {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#bs-divSearchButton #bs-Button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#socialMediaBottons{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 50vh;
}

#GifDisplay {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[image of site showing buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXqkJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate you're trying to use Flexbox, but in this case it's not the right tool for the job.

You should use either `absolute` or `fixed` positioning (depending on what you're going for) to get the social buttons in the bottom corner. Just make sure `body` has `position:relative`.

```
body { position:relative }
#socialMediaBottons { position:fixed; bottom:10px; right:10px; }
#fbButton, #twitterButton { display:inline-block; }
```

This way, whatever height or width the viewport is, the buttons will always be a specified distance from the bottom right corner (you can adjust `bottom` and `right` to your liking).

Comment: And what happens when the OP adds more content to the page? The social media buttons will cover it up.

Comment: @hungerstar Your question should be directed at the OP. They asked how to stick the socials in the bottom corner, so I assume there is margin in that area to accommodate.

Comment: Is that margin going to be modified with media queries for various viewport displays? IMHO, creating a footer and placing the social media buttons in it and doing away with `fixed` or `absolute` positioning would be a much more solid and less brittle approach.

Comment: They said it's responsive so I would hope the necessary adjustments are made, but I agree a static footer seems like a much more appropriate home for social buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This solution comes from the Bootstrap 4 page on Flex _

As recommended I added flex classes `d-flex justify-content-end` to the div `#socialMediaBottons` and removed the same from your CSS

So now the HTML section looks like this:

```
<div id="socialMediaBottons" class="d-flex justify-content-end"> 
    <div id="twitterButton">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large"
        data-text="Search for a Gif!" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
      <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>

    <div id="fbButton">
      <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/GIPHY/" data-layout="button" data-size="large"><a
          target="_blank"
          href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse"
          class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a></div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

...while the pertinent CSS block only contains the height attribute:

```
#socialMediaBottons{
    height: 50vh;
}
```

As you can see from this image the buttons are now aligned:
[aligned buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbtRB.png)

---

Reference Docs:

Bootstrap 4 Flex: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS as below:

```
.socialMediaButton{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}

.socialMediaButtons {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    display: flex;
}
```

See [result here](https://jsfiddle.net/mLz36b4h/).

Comment: And what happens when the OP adds more content to the page? The social media buttons will cover it up.

Comment: You're right. I suppose we could remove `bottom: 10px;` in that case

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue. It moves the social media buttons up. The same effect will happen.

Comment: They do appear to move down as more content is added

Comment: You got me...  Doing some research it looks like using `justify-content: flex-end; display: flex;` is a better solution.